# Predicate with DynamicExpression.ParseLambda

Tags: c#

I am constructing a dynamic filtering on list. I will receive a predicate from UI (like "Name == "Australia"") and the code should filter the list. It's working fine for "==" operator.
However I am struggling with below conditions and not sure how UI will pass the below conditions in predicate.

1. Contains
2. Starts With
3. End With
4. Not Equal To
5. Greater Than
6. Less Than
7. Between

I have copied my source code below. Help here would be appreciated.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lst = new List<Myclass>();

            lst.Add(new Myclass { Name = "Australia", Id = 1, Dt = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(10) });
            lst.Add(new Myclass { Name = "USA", Id = 2, Dt = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(5) });
            lst.Add(new Myclass { Name = "India", Id = 3, Dt = System.DateTime.Now});

            var result = lst.AsQueryable().Where(DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<Myclass, bool>("Name == \"Australia\""));
            var r = result.ToList();

        }
    }

    public class Myclass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Dt { get; set; }
    }
```

I think I found the predicate which I need.

```
Text Field Equal To = string exp = "(Name =\"India\")";
Text Field NOT Equal To = string exp = "(Name !=\"India\")";
Text Field Contains = string exp = "(Name.Contains (\"Ind\"))";
Text Field Starts With = string exp = "(Name.StartsWith (\"Ind\"))";
Text Field Ends With = string exp = "(Name.EndsWith (\"a\"))";

Number Field Equal to = string exp = "(Id = 1)";
Number Field Between with multiple conditions = string exp = "(Id > 1 AND Id <= 3) OR Id =3";
Number Field Between and greater than equal to = string exp = "(Id > 1 AND Id >= 3)";

Date Field Between  = string exp = "(Dt > Convert.ToDateTime(\"2/5/2021 4:46:04 AM\") AND Dt >= Convert.ToDateTime(\"2/3/2021 4:46:04 AM\"))";
```

Comment: "However I am struggling with below conditions" - what did you try and what happened?

Comment: I tried with predicate "Name Like \"%Australia%\"" but it's throwing exception..I am not sure how to write a predicate for like.

Comment: What exception is it throwing? What's the exception type and message?

Comment: This question can be closed as I found a solution to my problem. I have updated my question with answer.

Comment: @Machindra Feel free to post it as an actual answer below - answering your own question also means you can accept the answer (you get rep + the question isn't listed as "unanswered" anymore)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you for your suggestion but I don't see a option to answer my own question.

Comment: There's a big blank text box below, underneath it there's a blue button saying "Post your answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the predicate which I need.

```
Text Field Equal To = string exp = "(Name =\"India\")";
Text Field NOT Equal To = string exp = "(Name !=\"India\")";
Text Field Contains = string exp = "(Name.Contains (\"Ind\"))";
Text Field Starts With = string exp = "(Name.StartsWith (\"Ind\"))";
Text Field Ends With = string exp = "(Name.EndsWith (\"a\"))";

Number Field Equal to = string exp = "(Id = 1)";
Number Field Between with multiple conditions = string exp = "(Id > 1 AND Id <= 3) OR Id =3";
Number Field Between and greater than equal to = string exp = "(Id > 1 AND Id >= 3)";

Date Field Between  = string exp = "(Dt > Convert.ToDateTime(\"2/5/2021 4:46:04 AM\") AND Dt >= Convert.ToDateTime(\"2/3/2021 4:46:04 AM\"))";
```